# Multitouch Android, simple aplication doesn't work, why?

Tags: android, eclipse, touch, multi-touch

i tried to make a simple application to learn how to make a mutlitouch, but it doesn't work properly, i have to touch a strange combination of buttons to initiate action, any ideas?

the code is there:
http://wklej.to/MnwGl

Comment: for the button I will use the OnClickListener instead of OnTouchListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to implement multitouch for seperate view objects.

hope this [link](http://www.passsy.de/multitouch-for-all-views/) helps